# Is the acronym GPS used by members of the public in countries like Russia or China, who have their own GNSS

Tags: gps

In the UK, and countries using the GNSS controlled by America, the acronym GPS (Global Positioning System)  is used to describe the data. I was wondering if members of the public in countries like Russia or China, who have their own GNSS, use a different term to describe GNSS data or whether, because of the proliferation of technologies using GPS, it is a term used across GNSS systems?